# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript, typeerror

The following code, meant for a collapsible text is throwing out the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at HTMLButtonElement. the line where the error is spotted is: `if (levcontent.style.maxHeight){`

The code for the collapsible text is as follows:

```
<style>
    .collapsible {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #444;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    margin: 2% 4% 2% 4%;
    width: 93%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.lev-active, .collapsible:hover {
    background-color: #555;
}

.collapsible:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.lev-active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

.levcontent {
     padding: 0 18px;
     max-height: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
     transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
     background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>

<p><button class="collapsible">Levering</button></p>
<div class="levcontent">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>


<script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("lev-active");
    var levcontent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (levcontent.style.maxHeight){
      levcontent.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      levcontent.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
</script>
```

Has anyone an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The button is the only child of the `p` element. So there is no `nextElementSibling`.
You could either remove the `p` element or set `levcontent` to `this.parentElement.nextElementSibling`.

Furthermore I found a little typo: You used `content.scrollHeight` instead of `levcontent.scrollHeight` in the else block.

Here is the modified and working code:

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("lev-active");
    var levcontent = this.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
    if (levcontent.style.maxHeight){
      levcontent.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      levcontent.style.maxHeight = levcontent.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #444;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    margin: 2% 4% 2% 4%;
    width: 93%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.lev-active, .collapsible:hover {
    background-color: #555;
}

.collapsible:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.lev-active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

.levcontent {
     padding: 0 18px;
     max-height: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
     transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
     background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<p><button class="collapsible">Levering</button></p>
<div class="levcontent">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```