# Why my collapsible button doesn’t collapse?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I'd like to add to my (localhost) WordPress site a collapsible button with the following features:

- button width has not to be 100% but has to adapt to the text inside the button
- button can be inserted in a line of text without forcing the words after the button to go to the next line (I tried the plugin collapse-o-matic but the words after the button, even if they are written in the same line, are forced to go to the next line)

To better understand you can see this image

[image]

I was looking for how to manually (without plugins) create the button, and I ended up to a w3schools page where, using the online editor, I created the button I want (image above) whose code is the following

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}

.ccontent {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .3s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 3px inset rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60);
}
```

```html
Does <button class="collapsible">this</button> work?
<div class="ccontent">
  <p>Yes!</p>
</div>
Good job!
```

Next, I tried to figure out how to add the code to WordPress, so this is what I did

- added .collapsible and .content to the style.css file
- added the javascript to the footer using a plugin

then in a post I wrote the following code

```
Does <button class="collapsible">this</button> work?
<div class="ccontent"><p>Yes!</p></div>
Good job!
```

but, while the button is correctly showing, when clicking on it nothing happens. Since the button is showing, I think the problem has to do with the javascript code.
This is what is shown in my post

[image]

as you can see another problem is the blank space between the first line and the second.

I'm almost sure that the javascript is loaded because when I open the page source (CTRL+U) I see that, some line before the </body> tag, the script is shown.

Comment: Could you add above this.classList.toggle("active"); some console.log in order to see does this even trigger?

Comment: did you miss css of active class ?

Comment: @LazarNikolic pardon me for my ignorance, but does it mean that I have to write `console.log` on a blank line before `this.classList.toggle("active");` ?

Comment: yes, and then go to console of yuor browser and see does that text from console appear when you click on the button

Comment: @LazarNikolic ok thanks, I'm inspecting the button using the console tool of chrome, and when I click on the button this message appears `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null` and clicking on it this line is highlighted `if (content.style.maxHeight){`

Comment: ok. this means that the value of your var content is undefined or null. So, this line var content = this.nextElementSibling; is the one that is causing a problem for you.

Comment: @LazarNikolic this seems to be the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50485340/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-style-of-null-at-htmlbuttonelement-a

Comment: It could be... Try to implement what was written there

Comment: @LazarNikolic It worked many thanks! Now I have just to figure out what is the cause of the blank space between the line containing the button and the next line. I guess I have to adjust that via css, right?

Comment: yes. If it is working now, you can delete or close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown here [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50485340/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-style-of-null-at-htmlbuttonelement-a) to let the buttons work is enough to edit

`var content = this.nextElementSibling;`

in

`var content = this.parentElement.nextElementSibling;`

---

To remove the blank space is enough to place `margin: -20px 0;` inside the `.ccontent` CSS.